# Unknown Outcomes

Tags: riddle, knowledge

I'm going to try my hand at one of these Riley riddles. Enjoy, hope it's not too easy!

```
My prefix is 1, he would agree.

My infix encourages applause, whatever it may be.

My suffix is a rize of the Nag a' Rams, I guarantee.

The outcome of the whole thing, you can't foresee.
```

What am I?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Randomizer

My prefix is 1, he would agree.

> **Rand** - [Rand al'Thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373/rand-althor)

My infix encourages applause, whatever it may be.

> **OM** - not sure about this one, may be [Order of Merit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_Merit), a prestigious honour worthy of applause. 
>  Alternatively, could be referring to [Om](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Om) - "What is the sound of one hand clapping?"

My suffix is a rize of the Nag a' Rams, I guarantee.

> **izer** - anagram of rize as pointed out by rhsquared

The outcome of the whole thing, you can't foresee.

> You won't be able to predict the outcome of a true randomizer

Answer (score 6):

The word:

> **monopolizer** because it matches the prefix and suffix because
>  the prefix mono means one, single
>  the suffix izer is an anagram (nag a ram) of rize
>  I can't figure out how the inflix will work out though.
>
>
>  Further to the comment that mono is not the right prefix, other
>  valid words that match the suffix are
>  unionizer and unitizer but again I can't figure out what the 
>  inflix might be.

Comment: The suffix is correct! I had something else in mind for the prefix, though.

Comment: @RickvanOsta I gave it another shot but still answer is incomplete.